# Breaking captcha with a neural network - Learning deep learning

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I would like to implement a neural network allow to make captcha recognition. Actually, I'm new in deep learning that's the first neural network I'm building.

I have seen a another similar project on Github : https://deepmlblog.wordpress.com/2016/01/03/how-to-break-a-captcha-system/

However, I'm not able to understand it. I don't know what's a vgg base neural network model, etc ...

I was wondering if there is a course or courses that I could follow in order to be able to implement such a neural network. I don't know where to start ...

I don't aim to become an expert for the moment, I just want to first concretely discover this science that seems exciting.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommondation is a course from Stanford, [Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual Recognition](http://cs231n.github.io/).

But: This will not provide you easy to understand code to break captchas. You will learn the concept of Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN), which are popular in the classification of images.

As a reminder: Captchas are built to prevent computers from automatically filling them in. Even if nowadays techniques might be able to solve them, your project might be a bad idea (especially from the legal perspective).